# How to write Hello World for OpenWRT and/or dd-wrt

Tags: openwrt, broadcom, dd-wrt

I'm working on running a Hello World program on the Linksys WRT54G-V4 running either dd-wrt or OpenWRT.

Right now this router is running dd-wrt for reasons I'll explain below. I'd like to switch this router to OpenWRT, because I've not been able to build dd-wrt or its toolchain.  I 'assume' that the OpenWRT toolchain should produce executable binaries that will run on dd-wrt also.

OpenWRT was pretty straightforward to build, since it has a nice menu driven make system. Using this handy tool I built a toolchain that will cross compile from my x86 Ubuntu box to a MIPS target.

Following the instructions I've been able to build OpenWRT and produce images for brcm47xx and brcm63xx.

For example, here is a successful compile of my little Hello World program:

```
jim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tests$ cat helloC.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return 0;
}
jim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tests$
jim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tests$ mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc -o HelloWorld helloC.c
jim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tests$
jim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tests$ file HelloWorld
HelloWorld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), with unknown capability 0xf41 = 0x756e6700, with unknown capability 0x70100 = 0x3040000, not stripped
jim@ubuntu:~/Desktop/tests$
```

Sadly, when I try to run HelloWorld on my WRT54G-V4 running dd-wrt I get a seg fault.

Looking at Wikipedia, I see that this router uses the Broadcom BCM5352.

When I run make menuconfig in by OpenWRT/trunk directory I don't see an option for the BCM5352, which is why I'm reluctant to flash my router with one of the images I've created in the brcm47xx or brcm63xx directories. I don't want to guess wrong and brick the router.

**Question 1** - Which Broadcom configuration should I select using make menuconfig to target my WRT54G-V4 with its BCM5352 chipset?

**Question 2** - Should my 'HelloWorld' executable file I generated above run directly from the command line on the 54G, or must I make it a package per http://www.gargoyle-router.com/wiki/doku.php?id=openwrt_coding ?

TIA

Comment: I'm not at all sure you've got your toolchain set up correctly on Ubuntu :(  Look here:  http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/devel/crosscompile

Comment: I was able to get it working, I didn't have the correct version of open-wrt.  I'll come back and answer my question as to exactly what I did latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the official howto (from: http://www.dd-wrt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=21499&sid=de90601a8d51747d1c8ccec29284127d)

```
1. The helloworld.c source
Code:   
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {
        printf( "Hello world!\n" );
}   

2. Get and unpack the toolchain in your homedir
Code:   
cd ~
wget ftp://ftp.dd-wrt.com/sourcecode/toolchains.x86.debian.sp1.tar.bz2
tar -jxf toolchains.x86.debian.sp1.tar.bz2  

3. Add the path to your cross-compiler executable to your path environment variable and compile helloworld.c
Code:   
PATH=~/toolchains/4.1.0-uclibc-0.9.28/bin:$PATH mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld  

4. Check if its correctly compiled with the cross-compiler
Code:   
file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped  

5. Finally, transfer the helloworld binary file to your router, set the executable bit and run it.
```

Tested with Ubuntu 6.06.1 LTS.